# var_dump and simpleXML?

Tags: php

I'm loading an XML file in via simpleXML. I'm a novice at best at PHP and new to parsing PHP but I'm a little confused

I'm trying to understand the structure of the variable I have stored, so I tried var_dump()

The thing that's confusing me is the data I'm looking for that's in the XML is *not* anywhere in the dumped data

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=surfing&max-results=25

That's the URL I'm using at the moment. However, for example, the duration/seconds is nowhere to be found in the dumped variable data-- where is it and how do I access it?

here is the output I'm getting: http://pastebin.com/ggumXTEu

Comment: Well, it's not possible to `var_dump` it. All the data is stored in the libxml php resources internally and isn't available to just dump it.

Comment: the data is getting dumped, but not all of it, which is what's confusing me

here's the output I'm getting:

http://pastebin.com/ggumXTEu

Comment: what data is not being shown?

Comment: it shows, for example, the duration in seconds in the xml feed but it doesn't appear in the var dump.

"<yt:duration seconds='972'/>" etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path to `<yt:duration>` is `/feed/entry/media:group/yt:duration/`

You don't see these elements when using var_dump(), because they belong to a namespace(media and yt).

You may use SimpleXMLElement->children() to access these elements, you need to supply the namespace-uri as argument to `children()`

```
<ol>
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=surfing&max-results=25');
foreach($xml->entry as $entry)
{
  $duration=$entry
              ->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/')
                ->group
                  ->children('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007')
                    ->duration
                      ->attributes()
                        ->seconds;
       printf('<li><strong>%s</strong>( %ds)</li>',$entry->title,$duration); 
}
?> 
</ol>
```